Tkinter canvas element won't move during callback
I have a canvas the size of my window, with images on each corner representing resizing grips.
When creating them I bound them to B1-Motion:
# Bind resize
self.canvas.tag_bind(key, "<B1-Motion>", lambda event, mode=k:self.drag_resize(event, mode))

After doing the resize calculations and updating the parent window size, I'm moving the grips into their new places. Something like this:
def drag_resize(self, event, mode):
# (...) long function calculating things like new width and height and resizing window
        # Move grip images into place
        for corner in self.corners:
            grip = self.canvas.gettags(corner)
            self.canvas.moveto(grip, new_w, new_h)

It works fine, except for the grip invoking drag_resize() at the moment. This one never moves.
On some level it makes sense you wouldn't want to alter whatever is invoking the function while it's active, but why this happens? I just got started with Tkinter, I'm not a coder and I'm sure I'm missing something.
I'm thinking of hiding the grip being "dragged" and creating a dummy clone just to have the correct visual feedback. How would you approach it?
Edit
I'm implementing the dummy workaround and noticed the active grips return "current" in addition to tag when printing out their canvas.gettags() contents. They do this for several other events like <ButtonPress> and <Enter>.
You can't do much to them while they're in the current state, nor get information from them. If the request doesn't return empty it'll error out with _tkinter.TclError: unknown option "current". Feels like a bug.
The one thing that works is tag_rise/tag_lower(). That's how I'm hiding them, and for coordinates which I need to pass to the dummy I'm just storing their last known location in a variable because I don't have many grips anyway.
